# Protractor cannot find angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to set up unit/e2e tests for the angular app. Following the instructions on the protractor web site and numerous other samples I have set it up and being able to run tests unless they are referring to the angular objects.
Here is the sample html page I want to have tests for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/angular-mocks.js"></script>

    .....
</head>
<body ng-controller="DefaultController">
```

...

The test:

```
describe('Logon page', function ()
{
    beforeEach(function ()
    {
        browser.get('default.html');

        angular.module("app");
    });

    it('should have a title', function ()
    {
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Logon');
    });
});
```

as soon as I run it I got an exception: "ReferenceEror: angular is not defined".
If I remove line "angular.module("app");" - it works fine.
By looking at console output of the protractor it looks like Protractor.waitForAngular() is internally called after I try to access "angular" object. But as far as I understand browser.get - should load it before?

I use angular 1.3.4 and protractor 1.4.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the `angular.module("app");` part? The code you write in a Protractor test does not run in the browser. It uses the browser API (through Selenium) but you don't have direct access to angular modules or other structures on the page you're testing.

I think you may have mixed up the concepts of unit tests and E2E tests. You'll need `angular.module("app");` just for unit tests.

Comment: I would like to test controller/service/etc. Like in the following article: [test controllers](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/06/introduction-to-unit-test-controllers/). Therefore I need to access angular objects.

Comment: You don't need Protractor for this, then. Unit tests can be executed with Karma runner. Protractor is used for end-to-end tests (that is, when you don't indent to test separate controllers, services, etc. but your application as a whole, usually with backend, database, etc.)

Comment: Ok. So if I understand you correctly protractor is never intended and cannot have access to the angular library. It works only with the end result. And If I want to run controller tests, etc - I must run them with Karma - there I can use those objects?

Comment: Yes, that's basically right. Protractor is used to test sites built with angular, but without knowing their internals.